# Comparing string to a character of another string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Here's my program so far. My intention is to have it so the if statement compares the letter in the string `letterGuessed` to a character in the string `userInputPhraseString`. Here's what I have. While coding in xCode, I get an "expected '['"error. I have no idea why.

```
NSString *letterGuessed = userInputGuessedLetter.text;
NSString *userInputPhraseString = userInputPhraseString.text;

int loopCounter = 0;
int stringLength = userInputPhraseString.length;

while (loopCounter < stringLength){
    if (guessedLetter isEqualToString:[userInputPhraseString characterAtIndex:loopIndexTwo])
        {
        //if statement true
        }
    loopCounter++;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you asked a specific question.

Comment: your code makes no sense to me

Comment: `"Expected '['"`  It even points to the exact spot  where it expects it at...  it couldn't be any more clear...

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you learn how to program before attempting to work with Objective-C.  It is not a beginner's language.

Comment: guessedLetter, where is this variable? And the loopIndexTwo? Where are those. And on what line is that error occuring? Have you tried cmd+shift+k (clean) and complete reboot of xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do.. But I suppose that letterGuessed has one character... And that userInputPhraseString has many characters. So you want to know if letterGuessed is inside userInputPhraseString correct?

This is one solution without loops involved.. I replaced the input with fixed values for testing and tested the code.. It works.

```
NSString *letterGuessed = @"A"; //Change to your inputs
NSString *userInputPhraseString = @"BBBA"; //Since it has A it will be true in the test

NSCharacterSet *cset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:letterGuessed];
NSRange range = [userInputPhraseString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:cset];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) { //Does letterGuessed is in UserInputPhraseString?
    NSLog(@"YES"); //userInput Does contain A...
} else {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

In regards to your code... I fixed a couple of errors, first you are trying to get a UniChar (Integer) value for the character and want to compare it to a NSString which is an Object. Also fixed a couple of issues with syntax you had and used the right approach which is to return a range of characters. Again for doing what you want to accomplish the example above is the best approach I know, but for the sake of learning, here is your code fixed.

```
NSString *letterGuessed = @"A"; //Change to your inputs
NSString *userInputPhraseString = @"BBBA"; //Since it has A it will be true in the test

NSInteger loopCounter = 0; //Use NSInteger instead of int. 
NSInteger stringLength = userInputPhraseString.length;
BOOL foundChar = NO; //Just for the sake of returning NOT FOUND in NSLOG

while (loopCounter < stringLength){
    //Here we will get a letter for each iteration.
    NSString *scannedLetter = [userInputPhraseString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(loopCounter, 1)]; // Removed loopCounterTwo
    if ([scannedLetter isEqualToString:letterGuessed])
    {
        NSLog(@"FOUND CHARACTER");
        foundChar = YES;

    }
    loopCounter++;
}

if (!foundChar) NSLog(@"NOT FOUND");
```

NSRange holds the position, length.. So we move to a new position on every iteration and then get 1 character.

Also if this approach is what you want, I would strongly suggest a for-loop.

Comment: While technically correct and a vastly better approach, there's no explanation offered as to WHY this is better.  Moreover, this doesn't answer the actual question of what's WRONG with his code, which I feel is especially important given he's read the error message and claims he STILL has no idea.  Not teaching users how to make sense of the error messages they get is the surest way to guarantee a steady flow of terrible questions on SO.

Comment: I would not attempt to recover your down vote. But I don't agree. He didn't make a specific question. What is wrong with his code I don't know. But this should teach him something new and I think it will enrich his knowledge to best practices. Any how I don't think I deserve the down vote... Anyhow. Such is life.

Comment: You've now at least edited in an explanation.  I still think any answer in here should at a minimum address syntax error he has.  Now that the explanation has been added, I'll remove the downvote.  But unexplained code snippets are not helpful in the slightest.  I'd rather answer that offer explanation and no code rather than just code for some fool to copy & paste and come ask another bad question next week since they didn't learn anything by copy & pasting a code snippet offered as an "answer" without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing enclosing square brackets on this line:

```
    if (guessedLetter isEqualToString:[userInputPhraseString characterAtIndex:loopIndexTwo])
```

It should be:

```
    if ([guessedLetter isEqualToString:[userInputPhraseString characterAtIndex:loopIndexTwo]])
```

**Edit** that won’t fix your problem, though, because `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, not an `NSString`.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to fix that problem... but two more have risen. One is "Implicit conversion of "unichar" to "NSString* is dissallowed by ARC." and "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'unichar' to paramater of type NSString*

Comment: See my edit. The problem is that you are passing a `unichar` to a method that takes a parameter of type `NSString`. See Kiko Lobo’s answer for a faster, more idiomatic way to solve your problem.